# Upgrade bootstrap from 3 to 4 in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.5

Right now I have bootstrap 3 and I want to update it to 4 in laravel 5.5

So I guess I have to change my composer file

from

```
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
```

to

```
"bootstrap": "4.0.0",
"popper.js": "^1.12.6",
```

That will install bootstrap 4 but how do I link it to my current application.
I don't know in which files laravel is referencing the bootstrap 3 files.

Comment: Laravel 5.6 already has bootstrap 4 so you can just compare the boilerplate e.g at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js#L14 and https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/sass/app.scss#L9

Comment: Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'. in C:\Users\Demo\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_variables.scss error when executing npm run dev

Comment: I changed those things that you mentioned but now my entire layout is broken. navbar disappeared and it seems as if its not linking to the boostrap styling. What do i do ?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is not backwards compatible so you also need to migrate your existing markup to a bootstrap 4 compatible style according to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#by-component if you have not already done so

Answer (score 0):

you can just download bootstrap 4 `bootstrap.css` and replace the content of `app.css` file in `public` directory or `public/css` diectory with the content of the downloaded file. And all is well, you can use it in all `*.blade.php` file.